# Alsamixer outputs only in mono (0M or M0) : How to get stereo output?

Tags: 16.04, sound, alsa, headphones, mono

I have been using Ubuntu 16.04 for sometime now and use Alsamixer to manage my sound settings (every restart sets my headphone to mute (MM) so it's been a ritual to first set that back to unmute (00) and carry on). By some misfortune, I pressed a key whilst in the Alsamixer UI which made my headphone slot set to Mono output (0M or M0 - switched using the m key). How do I restore it back to stereo?

M0 plays audio only in the right ear. 0M plays only in the left.

Screenshot for 0M state
[image: Screenshot for 0M state]

Screenshot for M0 state
[image: Screenshot for M0 state]

Answer (score 2):

The solution turns out to be toggling individual output channels. You can mute left and right channels independently by using `, (or <)` and `. (or >)` respectively.